# Как из функции сделать рекурсивную функцию?

Tags: c++, рекурсия, системы-счисления

Для заданного целого десятичного числа N получить его представление в p-ичной системе счисления (p < 10). Нужно написать функцию и рекурсивную функцию. Не могу понять, как сделать рекурсию в этой функции. Помогите и объясните пожалуйста, если не сложно. Спасибо.

```
String DecToX (UINT num, BYTE p)
{
  String res0 = "", res = IntToStr(num) + " (10)   =   ";
  if (p>1 && p<10)
  {
    do
    {
      res0 = IntToStr(num%p) + res0;
      num/=p;
    }
    while (num>0);
    res += res0 + " (" + IntToStr(p) + ")";
  }
  else
    if (p==1)
    {
      for (UINT i = 0; i < num; i++)
        res0 += "0";
      res += res0 + " (1)";
    }
  else
    res = "Основание системы счисления p должно быть больше 0 и меньше 10.";
  return res;
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TForm1::Button1Click(TObject *Sender)
{
  ShowMessage(DecToX(973, 5));
}
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Кстати, *"Основание системы счисления p должно быть больше 0* — т.е. ваша программа работает и для `p==1`?

Answer (score 2):

Вот пример рекурсивной функции, преобразующей число n в систему счисления `2 <= p <= 10`.

Смысл: результат есть преобразование в p-ичную систему числа `n/p`, к которому приписана цифра `n%p` (`n = (n/p)*p + n%p`).

Заметим, кстати, что ваше

> Для заданного целого десятичного числа N

имеет смысл только если `N` — строка. Если `N` — число в памяти компьютера, то ни о какой десятичности говорить не приходится.

```
string toP(int n, int p)
{
    if (n == 0) return "";
    return toP(n/p,p) + to_string(n%p);
}
```

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin Теперь ответ более развернут? :)

Comment: да, несомненно. но плюс поставить у меня рука не поднимается: насколько вижу, на сам вопрос ответа в вашем сообщении всё-таки нет (спорить по этому поводу не берусь, соглашаясь заранее, что, вполне возможно, не прав в этом месте).

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin А по мне — ничего не изменилось :) Вот сейчас — дело другое. А было это все демонстрацией того, что развернутость ответа — скорее дело вкуса.